# Is there a way to use enthought packages in idle

Tags: package, python-idle, enthought

Is it possible to import packages downloaded in enthought package manager, into enthought idle?

Comment: If Idle has been started correctly (i.e. from Canopy User Python) then it will automatically have access to all the packages installed in package manager.

If this is not working for you, it is likely that you are starting Idle from an obsolete shortcut which does not actually refer to Canopy User Python. These shortcuts may be broken on some platforms (you don't say what your OS is). Since Canopy GUI does everything that Idle does, and much more, Canopy users almost never use Idle, so it has not been a priority to get these shortcuts working correctly.

Comment: @JonathanMarch i can use numpy etc but i cant use networkx for example, i can in enthought canopy gui,my operating system is windows 7. My idle.exe is located within enthought/canopy/system/scripts